# Edit Action in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my Edit Action method I want to save all the changes which I making when Invoking the edit action. But I think I am missing some think. This is what I am trying.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Person editPerson)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // may be here I want to add soething
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(editPerson);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Person editPerson)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(editPerson);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to save the Person object? Are you using Entity Framework or just plain sql? I presume because you're using MVC3 you're using Entity Framework. If i see your method you most likely are trying to Create a person then edit one. If you're editing your method will usually look like`public ActionResult Edit(int id, Person editPerson)`

In that case

```
using(SomeContext db = new SomeContext())
{
db.Persons.Add(editPerson);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

if editing

```
using(SomeContext db = new SomeContext())
{
Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
// Update your fields
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am not using any database. I just wanted to save in memory. I have got the solution. Thanks for provideing the various ways

Answer (score 0):

Because there are multiple ways in which to interact with the backing store, we would need more information on how are you doing so (Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, etc.). If you haven't checked it out, you should read Scott Hanselman's blog on [Exploring Different Database Options](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx) from the well-known [Nerd Dinner Tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm). This should steer you in the right direction. (Also, if you haven't played around with Nerd Dinner, I would highly recommend doing so at it is an excellent introduction to MVC and the various technologies surrounding it.)